# What's the easiest way to convert a Scala reflection MethodSymbol/MethodSignature to a Java Method?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, converters

Scala reflection is designed for both compilation time and run time. So it can identify polymorphic method more effectively than Java (see my previous post [In Scala Reflection, How to get generic type parameter of a concrete subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174763/in-scala-reflection-how-to-get-generic-type-parameter-of-a-concrete-subclass)), which suffers from type erasure.

However, this method can only be invoked using Scala reflection's mirror, which is slightly slower than its java counterpart, I would like to know if there is an easy way to convert Scala MethodSymbol, which is returned by Type.members:

```
import import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val tpe = typeTag[String].tpe
val methodSymbol = tpe.method("size": Name)
```

or MethodSignature, which is returned by Type.member.SignatureIn(Type):

```
val methodSignature = methodSymbol.typeSignatureIn(tpe)
```

to a Java method that can be directly invoked through Java reflection API:

```
val size = method.invoke("abc")
size: Int = 3
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to simulate Java-style invocation.

```
object ScalaMethodUtil {

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def invoke(m: MethodSymbol)(o: Any)(args: Any*): Any = {
    val mirror = runtimeMirror(o.getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(o)
    mirror.reflectMethod(m)(args: _*)
  }
}
```