# How to get the type parameters from an abstract class that is extended by an object

Tags: scala, reflection

Suppose I have an object that extends some abstract class

```
case class Id[T] private(v: String)

object SomeObj extends SomeAbstractClass[SomeCaseClass, AnotherObj.type, Id[SomeCaseClass]]
```

Would it be possible to get the following type parameters from SomeObj at runtime?

- SomeCaseClass
- AnotherObj.type
- Id[SomeCaseClass]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these imports and definitions (for a self-contained example):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
trait Foo[A, B, C]
object Bar extends Foo[Int, String, Option[Short]]
```

Explicitly referring to `Bar.type`:

```
internal
  .thisType(typeOf[Bar.type].typeSymbol.asClass)
  .baseType(typeOf[Foo[_,_,_]].typeSymbol.asClass)
  .typeArgs
```

Without referring to `Bar.type`:

```
val a: Any = Bar // pretend that it's some instance, not necessarily `Bar`
val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
internal
  .thisType(m.reflect(a).symbol.asClass)
  .baseType(typeOf[Foo[_,_,_]].typeSymbol.asClass)
  .typeArgs
```

Both gives:

```
List(
  scala.Int,
  String,
  scala.Option[scala.Short]
)
```

Both solutions inspired by [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174763/in-scala-reflection-how-to-get-generic-type-parameter-of-a-concrete-subclass).

Comment: I'm wondering what type erasure actually mean now if we still can restore generic types at runtime ..

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko This works only if all type arguments are fixed during class/object definition. In case of singletons, it works because if there is only one instance of a given class, the type parameters can't vary at all, so it's just looking up constants. It doesn't help with finding whether an empty list was originally `List[Int]` or `List[String]`, because `List` is not a singleton.